# Can billing name/address not be pre-populated on Event Registration Page?

Tags: civievent, civicontribute, contribution-page, online-registration, billingblock

The pre-populated Billing Name and address information on the Event Registration Page is causing many credit card authorizations to be declined (Authorization.net payment processor).

Is there a way to make these fields:

1. Not be pre-populated?
2. Make the "My billing address is the same as above" checkbox not default to being checked (and then if checked the fields populate)?
3. Editing which fields are present in this field grouping?

Civi: 5.42.1
Joomla: 3.10.4

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid to say its not possible without implementing [hook_civicrm_buildForm](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_buildForm/) hook via extension or module or plugin.